# Binding with ValidatesOnException throws Unhandled-Error in .Net4

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, c#-4.0

I encountered a very annoying change for me from .NET3.5 to .NET4.0.
When using a ExceptionValidationRule on a binding for validating the exception thrown in the bound properties setter gets handled by the binding in 3.5. In 4.0 it is thrown as unhandled while debugging.

Changing the target framework from 3.5->4.0 in this small example (new WPF Application project) shows the problem:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private string _field = "Test";
        public string Property
        {
            get { return _field; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length < 4)
                    _field = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <TextBox Width="300"
             Height="100"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Property, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Window>
```

Is it possible to have these exceptions handled at debug time in .NET4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `IDataErrorInfo` and `ValidatesOnDataErrors` instead. Not only do you not run into these kinds of situations, but you avoid the tangible performance penalty of bubbling exceptions up the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunatly I have to handle a large chunk of legacy models, which all throw some sort of ValidationExceptions. Also freeing up the indexers for IDataErrorInfo makes refactoring quite intensive.

Comment: Most of the time I implement IDataErrorInfo explicitly on my view model base class to keep the indexer free and provide a better validation interface. As far as your legacy model goes, you may be able to craft a regex to make a call to your new protected SetValidationError method to make refactoring easier. Just a thought.